# Need help understanding why my Javascript remoting doesn't work on a standard Page Layout

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

This is driving me nuts.  I have the most simple JSRemoting setup and for whatever reason I can not get this VF page to render on my Contact Layout.  It's giving me a cross domain error and the only way that I can fix it seems to be to remove the @RemoteAction annotation from the controller/extension.  I searched the net and saw other people were able to remote from a standard layout and I thought JSRemoting was supported in this use case?

Anyway, I'm getting this error from the console :

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://c.cs20.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://cs20.salesforce.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Even if I am not referencing the remote action I get it but if I remove the **@RemoteAction** annotation, the error goes away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the super simple code I'm trying to use :

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="jrTesting" 

showHeader="false" >
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap3, 'bootstrap_3.1.1/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js')}"/><apex:messages />
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="ts" >This is my paragraph...</p>



<script type="text/javascript">

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {

console.log($j("#ts").text());

$j("#ts").text("New Text here!");
callRA();
callRA2();
});



function callRA() {
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.jrTesting.getTheString}',
            function(r, e){           
             $j("#ts").text(r);  
            });

}

function callRA2() {
jrTesting.getTheString(function(r, e){           
             $j("#ts").text(r + ' from number 2!');  
            });

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

controller :

```
public with sharing class jrTesting {

    public jrTesting() {

    }




    @RemoteAction
    public static string getTheString() {
        return 'Here is my return string';
    }

}
```

****UPDATE**
To access it, the class and methods need to be global!**

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your response, @Regal.  Well, after reading further, I am a dummy!  Apparently you have to make your class and method **Global**!  Anyway, for anyone else out there banging their head on the table about this, you can find the answer in the JSRemoting documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)

```
@RemoteAction Scope Visualforce Page    Non-Global Component    Global Component    

iframe
Global Remote Method    Allowed Allowed Allowed Allowed
Public Remote Method    Allowed Allowed Error   Error
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says: The remoting url of the visualforce page is different from the url of Standard layout page So, browser security do not allow this cross domain request.

Visualforce remoting is a stateless ajax call which cannot be happened to different url,port or protocol from the url in which it initiated.

You can see remote url is: https://c.cs20.visual.force.com/ and page url is https://cs20.salesforce.com/
They have different domains. To make this call successful, domain,protocol and port must be same.

I would recommend to use `<apex:actionfunction>` if you can use Apex controller on visualforce page.