# Controller not found in Inline visualforce page

Tags: javascript-remoting, inline-visualforce

I am getting this error in the inline vf page:

```
Controller not found for 'CloudFilesController'
```

while no such error comes when I open the vf page directly without using it as inline page.

VF page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Lead" extensions="CloudFilesController">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
       var loadFiles = function() {
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.CloudFilesController.getFiles}',
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {
                        console.log(result);
                    } else {
                        console.log('some error occurred');
                    }
                });
        } 
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

CloudFilesController:

```
public with sharing class CloudFilesController {

    public CloudFilesController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static List<CloudFile__c> getFiles() {
       return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to make my method and class global in the controller. Thanks to this answer [Need help understanding why my Javascript remoting doesn't work on a standard Page Layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46048/need-help-understanding-why-my-javascript-remoting-doesnt-work-on-a-standard-pa)

Answer (score 0):

The SFDC doc say something about this: 
[image]

Comment: The controller and action exists. It's not just a warning,  functionality is also not working